# How can you turn a floated div into an absolutely positioned one in the same exact position and dimensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you turn a floated div into an absolutely positioned one in the same exact position and dimensions? I'm using jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried saving position and dimension to variable, then set the position to absolute and then use CSS to set position/dimension again ?

Comment: This depends on a lot - width, height, float direction, parent elements - do you have some code you can post?

Comment: Some code might be handy, btw why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply that: [jsfiddle.net/MKLXk](http://www.jsfiddle.net/MKLXk/3/)

```
$('.turnmeabsolute').click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).position();  

    $(this).css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: pos.top,
        left: pos.left        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's floated left and it is inside another container then to the parent element add this to the css:

```
position: relative;
```

Then for the item your working with:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

This is also assuming the width and height are already defined.

If you can provide some source code that would help out a bit more and we can provide a better answer.